# Can a person be "responsible" to another person?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

I came across this statement in a policy/guideline text: "He/she is responsible to the MD for maintaining the accuracy of this Guidelines. The Guidelines shall be adopted annually by the MD even if no amendments are made."  ´...responsible to the MD...´ was used to emphasize the person´s responsibility. Is this proper use of the verb "responsible"?

Comment: Hello, Audrey. The Help Center lists the types of questions considered good questions on ELU. Have you done any of your own research here? Do you agree that a Google search gives over 26 000 000 hits for "responsible to"? Aren't the first returns mainly addressing your question? Isn't the 'Language Portal of Canada' article (top of the list when I looked) spot on?

Answer (score 1):

I share the OP's sense that *responsible* is an odd choice in the following excerpt:

> He/she is responsible to the MD for maintaining the accuracy of this Guidelines. The Guidelines shall be adopted annually by the MD even if no amendments are made.

Assuming that "this Guidelines" actually appears in the original wording, the excerpt suggests a writer who either isn't very careful or has an unsteady grasp of English.

With regard to *responsible*, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has a helpful usage note about the related terms *responsible*, *answerable*, *accountable*, *amenable*, and *liable*:

> RESPONSIBLE, ANSWERABLE, ACCOUNTABLE, AMENABLE, LIABLE mean subject to being held to account. RESPONSIBLE implies holding  specific office, duty, or trust {the bureau *responsible* for revenue collection}. ANSWERABLE suggests a relation between one having a moral or legal obligation and a court or other authority charged with oversight of its observance {an intelligence agency *answerable* to Congress}. ACCOUNTABLE suggests imminence of retribution for unfulfilled trust or violated obligation {elected officials are *accountable* to the voters} AMENABLE and LIABLE stress the fact of subjection to review, censure, or control by a designated authority under certain conditions {laws are *amenable* to judicial review} {not *liable* for the debts of the former spouse}.

Although I'm not sold on the commentary about *amenable* (because I most often see that word in the context of phrases like "I am amenable to X," where the sense of the statement is "I would find X acceptable"), the rest of the MW discussion seems to me to reflect normal U.S. usage quite well. Especially noteworthy are the prepositions after the various words—*to* after *accountable*, *amenable*, and *answerable*; and *for* after *liable* and *responsible*. In my view, these are indeed the usual prepositions associated with each word when used in the sense discussed in the usage note, although "liable to" is idiomatically common in the sense of "likely to" or "a threat to."

Applying these distinctions to the quoted policy guideline, I think that "He/she is responsible to the MD for maintaining the accuracy of th[ese] Guidelines" combines two distinct ideas ("responsible for maintaining the accuracy of these Guidelines" and "answerable [or *accountable*] to the MD) under one roof ("responsible to X for Y"). As a reader, I can see what the author means, but I don't think that assigning double duty to *responsible* is a particularly effective way to convey that meaning clearly.

If I were responsible for maintaining the accuracy of the guidelines—or for that matter, if I were responsible for ensuring that the guidelines became accurate, to the extent that they were not so at the outset—I would use different adjectives to express the two duties with maximum clarity:

> He/she is responsible for maintaining the accuracy of these Guidelines, and is answerable to the MD for performing this duty appropriately. The Guidelines shall be adopted annually by the MD even if no amendments have been made to them in the interim.

Is "responsible to X for Y" grammatically improper? No, I don't think so. Is it a poorer way to express the ideas of being responsible for Y and answerable to X than you'd get by spelling out those two ideas separately? In my subjective opinion, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's become very common for us to think of responsibility in a collective or organizational sense, so even though "is responsible to" is correct usage it's not surprising for it to *feel* out of place.

It may help though to realize that responsible is not a verb, but an adjective. It is therefore an attribute or state of existence. This attribute could be expounded as "under compulsion to answer to a person regarding..." 
Every time a person is responsible for something there is an implication of an individual or collective that they are acting on behalf of.
In this case the "responsible to" (the MD) and the "responsible for" (maintaining accuracy) are explicitly stated rather than implied.